# Default CSS Layout/Template for each themeroller

Tags: css, jquery-ui, themeroller

In the below code, I use smoothness theme from jQuery Themeroller. Here body style (text box and label) is different than my button style. Just want to know if Themeroller has default template/layout style for each theme. Here is my situation is to write a body and other tag styles myself and make it look similar to my Themeroller theme i use. Please share if you face similar scenarios and all your inputs are welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
</head>
    <link href="Styles/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("input[type='button']").button();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Name </td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="name" value="" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2> <input type="button" value="Details" id="details" /> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI doesn't yet have an enhanced text input element.

But you can use the jQuery UI CSS Framework to theme elements, eg:

```
<div class='ui-widget ui-corner-all'>
    <h3 class='ui-widget-header'>Enter your details</h3>
    <div class='ui-widget-content' style='padding: 1em'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><div class='ui-widget-header ui-corner-all'>Name</div></td>
                <td> <input type="text" id="name" value="" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2> <input type="button" value="Details" id="details" /> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

See http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API for reference.